# How do i get selected item from combobox which was created with datatable

Tags: c#, combobox

In my project, combobox values are coming in a method named "getArticles". Here is the method:

```
public void getArticles(ComboBox cb)
{
    var getAll = getAllFromDB("articles", "", "articleName ASC");
    DataTable dt = getAll.Tables["articles"];
    cb.DataSource = dt;
    cb.DisplayMember = "articleName";
    cb.ValueMember = "id";
}
```

"getAllFromDB" method is doing selection from articles table and returns DataSet. Now my problem is here. When i use `cb.SelectedValue` i can get id value of article name. This is Ok and good. But when i use `cb.SelectedItem` it is showing "System.Data.DataRowView".
Please could you help me, how can i get article name like using `cb.selectedItem`? 
 Kind regards.

Comment: You could use `cb.SelectedText` which i reckon is not the right way to do. Are you sure the display member set is appropriate? If it is you shouldnt get this error

Comment: Habib, are you sure there is a property on the combobox item object called "ArticleName"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following codes of lines, may be it will help to get the selected item.

```
        ComboBoxItem requiredItem = (ComboBoxItem)cboType.SelectedItem;
        string value = requiredItem.Content.ToString();
```

EDIT:

Sorry, the above ComboBoxItem will only works in the case of .Net Framework 4.5, it is in `System.Windows.Controls` namespace. Refer to following code parts for your answer and check

```
        DataTable dtable = (DataTable)comboBox1.DataSource;
        label1.Text = dtable.Rows[comboBox1.SelectedIndex][0].ToString();//gives you article id
        label2.Text = dtable.Rows[comboBox1.SelectedIndex][1].ToString();//gives you article name
```

Comment: What is ComboboxItem? Sorry for my beginner status.

Comment: Its a class, which represents the Item present in combobox

Comment: @HabipOĞUZ, refer now to my new answer.